# "do you want the application .ios.app to accept incoming network connections" popup diaplay every time

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

"do you want the application .ios.app to accept incoming network connections" popup diaplay every time when run Applition in simulator in MACwhen run app in xamarin forms

This issue occur when add Xamarin.TestCloud.Agent Package in ios project.

[image]

I select "Allow" and I see the app appear in "Security > Firewall > Firewall Options list of exceptions", but it continues to ask me every time.

when i am create new Blank Xamarin.Forms app it's working fine.

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You can open  the `Terminal.app` and type in the text below. Make sure that your app is not running while you do this.

```
sudo codesign --force --deep --sign - /Applications/xxx.app/
```

This will re-sign the app and the prompt will disappear. Note: You will get the prompt one more time after doing this, however it won't come up the next time.

You will see something like this in the terminal:

```
/xxx.app/: replacing existing signature
```

For more information you can access [here](http:///xxx.app/:%20replacing%20existing%20signature).